# Promise.resolve inside .then gives me undefined

Tags: javascript, promise

I don't know why my `promise.resolve` is returning undefined.

My code structure is like this:

```
const request = require('request-promise')
var lotteryid = function(){

  const option = {/* info about the request url */}
  request(option)
  .then(function(body){
     // do something
     // get some value from the body. let's call it x
     return promise.resolve(x)

  })
  .catch(function(err){
    // got any error
    return promise.reject(err)      
  })

}
```

After doing that, I call this function:

```
lotteryid.then(function(x){
    **x is undefined in my case** 

}).catch(function(err){

    return promise.reject(err)      
})
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: "my code structure is like this" — That won't compile. Show a real [mcve].

Comment: There are a few issues with your code. First, you aren't returning anything from `lotteryid`, so any code you're trying to attach after is falling on deaf ears.

Comment: "x is undefined in my case" — Are you sure it isn't `then` which is undefined?

Comment: You can get rid of `return promise.resolve(x)` and just do `return x`, also the catch part can be dropped.

Comment: Your `lotteryId()` function never `return`s anything. You need to `return` the promise that you get from `.then()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First error: is not `promise.resove` but `Promise.resolve`.

Second problem: you wait inside a non-async function and then return a resolved promise.

**EDIT: better solution (thanks to @Mikael Lennholm)**

```
const request = require('request-promise')
var lotteryid = function() {
  return request(option)
    .then(function(body) {
      // do something
      // get some value from the body. let's call it x
      return x
    })
}
```

And as before:

```
lotteryid.then(function(x) {
  // do_something(x)
})
.catch(function(err) {
  // console.error(err)
})
```

**OLD ANSWER:**
You can:

1. return a new promise and resolve it after you have done something on body

   ```
   const request = require('request-promise')
   var lotteryid = function() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(option)
          .then(function(body) {
            // do something
            // get some value from the body. let's call it x
           resolve(x)
          })
          .catch(function(err){
            // got any error
            reject(err)      
          })
      })
   }
   ```
2. make the function async and just return the value, like

   ```
   const request = require('request-promise')
   var lotteryid = async function() {
     request(option)
       .then(function(body) {
         // do something
         // get some value from the body. let's call it x
         return x
       })
   }
   ```

Thanks to Derek for the suggestion.

Comment: This looks like an anti-pattern, you can just use `return request(option)...` instead

Comment: if I understood what  Rikenm meant he must do something before return:
`// do something`
`// get some value from the body. let's call it x`

Comment: Even so, you're returning a promise of a promise. It makes more sense to just return the original promise, and you can do the same thing as the anti-pattern you have, does.

Comment: @AldoD. You can do whatever you need to do in the `then` callback: `return request(option).then(function(body) { /* get some value from the body. let's call it x */ return x})`. This is how promises are supposed to be used and why your solution is an anti-pattern. In short, you **never** need to create your own promise if you already get a promise from the function you call.

Comment: what if request(option) gives me some error.  Where should I catch it if I remove the .catch() as you say.

Comment: @Rikenm use `lotteryid.catch(function(err) { /* do_someting(err); */ })`